# VMWare ESXi, change the default path for a VM

Tags: configuration, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

For some reason VMWare ESXi has decided that one of my VMs is on a completely different path to the path it is actually on.

So my VM is on /vmfs/volumes/long-guid-here/my-vm-name but when I try to open it I get the message "File < unspecified filename> was not found." Which is not really surprising as unspecified filenames are *quite difficult* to locate.

I thought it was just the swap file, which was down in the .vmx file as /vmfs/volumes/long-guid-here/old-vm-name/old-vm-name.vmsd but when I changed that in the vmx it made no difference.

What I can't figure out is where VMWare is getting the old-vm-name from- when I look in the "Settings" pane it believes the working file location to be "[datastore-name] old-vm-name\" and I can't find anywhere to change it. Now the files themselves are all named for old-vm-name - so the directory is /my-vm-name/old-vm-name.vmx and so on. Is this the cause of my problems or is there some arcane configuration option elsewhere around the VMWare machine that I need to be tinkering with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that by removing the VM from the manifest on the server and then re-adding it by browsing the datastore and using the menu from there, the VM was restored with the correct paths and it now appears to start correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I had a jacked up VM with a bunch of orphaned snapshots. Moved them off the datastore and then the VM wouldnt start. Created a new one, pointed to the main vmdk and all is good now.